# how i should wait for a message reply from another actor in akka.net?

Tags: c#, actor, akka.net

Im new to akka.net and i have learned that in order to use the async and await pattern you would have to use the Ask() Method but as far as im understanding it , you can only await a task only if you fire a method within that actor or some object method, but is it possible to await a task that sends a message to another actor ?

let me illustrate by a simple example :

lets say ActorA received an Message and he needs some informations from ActorB, ActorA code would like this :

```
class ActorA :ReceiveActor
{
   public ActorA ()
   {
      Receive<string>(Message => ActorB.Ask<string>()); 
   }

}
```

lets say i want to stall waiting for a reply from actor B. i dont want to process any other messages. ActorB  listens for the request, process the message and then finnally replies.

the thing is when ActorB replies it must reply of the form ActorA.tell(replymessage), and this way ActorA might never get to process the reply because the replyMessage should go to ActorA mailbox.

Am i missing something !

Comment: What do you want to do if actor A never receives the message from actor B? Simply keep stalling?

Comment: @YikSanChan well i never thought about that ,i guess its a bad practice to do so

Comment: On the JVM, Akka's ask pattern spawns a single-purpose actor to receive the reply and complete the asynchronous future. I don't know if Akka.NET takes the same approach, but that approach does allow the asking actor to handle other messages; if you need to ignore or defer messages until the ask completes (or fails with a timeout) you can implement that fairly easily.

Comment: @ColinM that is absolutely not true. Akka.NET has no relationship to Proto.Actor - we are functioning and healthy OSS organization. The same cannot be said for them.

Comment: @ColinM from what i have read in ProtoActor website, akka.net faced major design issues at the begining and thats why  Roger Johansson created ProtoActor, but that they seem to have solved all those issues , its stable now and way much powerfull  than ProtoActor and its more mature, you should be careful more with your claims , you could easily misguide a newcomer to Akka.Net

Comment: I've deleted my comment and I apologize for my nonsense claim (more specifically to you @Aaronontheweb, I was not trying to defame Akka.NET in any way). It has been some time since I last read that (possibly on the ProtoActor site) and decided not to check up further on Akka.NET, but I have been proven wrong.

Comment: @ColinM it's no problem at all. You were just trying to help. All good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need request-response messaging in Akka.NET, you can use the `Ask` keyword and `ReceiveAsync`:

```cs
class ActorA :ReceiveActor
{
   public ActorA ()
   {
      ReceiveAsync<string>(async message => {
        var resp = await ActorB.Ask<string>("some input");

        // do some work
      }); 
   }

}
```

This will have your actor asynchronously wait until it receives a response before it moves on - but it's worth noting that this will *block* your actor from processing any other messages prior to the `await` call completing.

If you wanted to use one-way messaging to allow for interleaving of messages, you could also write it this way:

```cs
class ActorA :ReceiveActor
{
   public ActorA ()
   {
      Receive<MessageType>(message => {
        // some work
        ActorB.Tell("some command");
      }); 

      Receive<string>(message => {
        // receive response from ActorB
      }); 
   }
}
```

The difference is, there's no timeout or verification that the sender processed the message and sent a reply in the second model. But, it also requires fewer allocations and it allows `ActorA` to keep processing other messages in the background while the work is being done.

You can use either approach - I'd recommend the first if you absolutely need to guarantee that the message gets processed.

Comment: i want to follow the first approach but i still dont understand how ActorA can have a reply if actor B replies to actorA in this for ```ActorA.tell(Replymessage)``` , this  will send a message to ActorA mailbox and as we recall ActorA is stuck in the receive method so it cant process the message , or is there some other way ActorB can reply to ActorA ?

Comment: In order for `ActorB` to work with both of these cases, you'll want to send the reply this way: `Sender.Tell(ReplyMessage)` - that will both versions of this code to work.

Comment: what is the differnce between calling  ```Sender.Tell(ReplyMessage)```  and ```AcorA.Tell(ReplyMessage)```  since both will send A replyMessage to ActorA mailbox and actor is stuck in this line ```var resp = await ActorB.Ask<string>("some input");```

Comment: `Sender` is the actor reference that sends the current message that is being processed. You get this reference automatically from the context of the receive. Type wise, `ActorA` and `Sender` are exactly the same. Imagine adding `ActorC` to the mix, and `ActorC` behaves just like `ActorA`. The `Sender` property in `ActorB` can now be `ActorA` or `ActorC`, depending who was doing the `Ask()`-ing.

Comment: @Greg yeah i know that , what i meant by what is the diffrence between them , is in the answer provided by @Aaronontheweb , how come in my particular probem is it different to Reply with ```Sender.Tell(ReplyMessage)``` rather than ```ActorA.tell(ReplyMessag)``` since both of these send a ```ReplyMessage``` to ActorA mailbox ,so ActorA would never process the replyMessage since it is awaiting in the Receive Method. so it doesnt quite solve my problem to use ```Sender``` instead of ```ActorA```

Comment: @ezio Ask doesn't go back to ActorA's mailbox - Ask creates a temporary, single-use actor that closes the `TaskCompletionSource` whose `Task<T>` you `await` on. Replying to `Sender` allows `ActorB` to reply to either actor.